# Iterate an array using only select query in teradata

Tags: sql, select, teradata

I'm trying to achieve the output table using the input table. The input table contains id and name where id has the numerical values and name contains JSON value. I can get the output by writing a procedure query by using 'LOOP', 'Cursor' etc. But how can we achieve this same using select query statement in Teradata.

### Input table

| S.No | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "id": 4, "item" : ["Apple", "google", "IBM" ] } |

### Output table

| Id | Index | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | apple |
| 4 | 1 | google |
| 4 | 2 | ibm |

### Query

```
select * from json_table
(  
on 
  (
      select Name.jsonextractvalue("$.id.[*]) as memberid,
      Name
      from table_data 
  )
using rowexpr("$.name[*]"]
colexpr("")

) as A(member_id,index,name)
```

Comment: Your example isn't quite valid JSON, but apparently would have only a single key whose corresponding value is an array of strings. You could shred or just extract the array as a string value (e.g. using JSON_TABLE or JSON_EXTRACT) or even just convert the entire field to a string. Then apply STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE or REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE to that result to "iterate", i.e. break up into multiple rows.

Comment: I don't think json_table at least will work with that invalid json. At the least you need to quote the identifier - `"id" : ["apple"...`

Comment: Please find the updated question also with the query which i've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSONExtractValue / JSONExtract

```
WITH T AS (
SELECT CAST(name.JSONExtractValue('$.id') AS INTEGER) AS id,
  CAST(name.JSONExtract('$.item[*]') AS VARCHAR(4096)) AS itemlist
FROM  table_data
)
SELECT id, token_ndx-1 AS "Index", Name 
FROM TABLE(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(
T.id,
SUBSTRING(T.itemlist FROM 3 FOR LENGTH(T.itemlist)-4), /* remove [" and "] */
'","',  /* split at "," sequences */
'c') 
RETURNS(id INTEGER, token_ndx INTEGER, Name VARCHAR(100))) AS split;
```

Or with JSON_Table:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT id, itemlist
  FROM JSON_Table
    (ON (SELECT "S.id" AS Dummy, Name FROM table_data)
     USING ROWEXPR('$')
     COLEXPR('[ {"jsonpath" : "$.id", "type" : "INTEGER"},
                {"jsonpath" : "$.item", "type" : "VARCHAR(4096)"}
              ]')
    ) AS jt(Dummy, id, itemlist)
)
SELECT id, token_ndx-1 AS "Index", Name 
FROM TABLE(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(
 T.id,
 SUBSTRING(T.itemlist FROM 3 FOR LENGTH(T.itemlist)-4), /* remove [" and "] */
 '","', /* split at "," sequences */
 'c')
RETURNS(id INTEGER, token_ndx INTEGER, Name VARCHAR(100))) AS split;
```

Comment: Using the second part i am able to get the records , i had to use group by on those columns to remove the duplicates.. but not sure why we are getting duplicate records for every row  its returning 2 records , i.e. in the above example i got 6 records instead of 3.. Could you explain why

Comment: No idea. Both approaches work for me with the given sample table JSON as input. Also tested with multiple rows in the source table. I don't get any duplicates.